# Why do i receive the error, "Can't find variable: $(this)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I bought a magazine on web design. In this mag they had an example for how to make a jQuery slideshow in "one line of code". (I seems like with their reasoning, that any compressed code is one line...)

Any how...

I tried to implement their example, but i get an error (in the console) that it can't find the variable $(this).

The HTML code just contains:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/f.png" alt="f"></li>
        <li><img src="img/t.png" alt="t"></li>
        <li><img src="img/moon.png" alt="moon"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where all of the `img` tags has got the same position (on top of each other).

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

The script is now supposed to animate, change the opacity of the different elements within the `ul`
(which work for the first element animation).

[JSfiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/FJ8cu/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $("ul li:last").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function(){
            $("ul li:first").before($this);
            $(this).css({'opacity': 1})
        });
    },5000);

});
```

The error, as mentioned before, is "Can't find variable: $this". Which the console points to `.before($this)`.

Comment: because $this is undefined. Try $(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a variable called `$this`, you can just use the dom element reference `this` to relocate the element like

it should be `$("ul li:first").before(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jQuery object of the current element like this

```
$("ul li:first").before($(this));
```

Check the brackets around `this`